# Risk-return trade-off — solving a convex optimzation

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I try to convert a convex optimisation (cvxopt) example to the Wolfram Language from python. Source of the python code: [Risk-return trade-off](http://cvxopt.org/examples/book/portfolio.html)

Please advise me on how to convert the following python code into Wolfram Language.

```
xs = [ qp(mu*S, -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] for mu in mus ]
```

I have completed the first few lines

```
n = 4;
S = 
  {{ 4.0^-2.0, 6^-3.0, -4.0^-3, 0.0},
   {6.0^-3.0, 1.0^-2.0, 0.0, 0.0},
   {-4.0^-3, 0.0, 2.5^-3, 0.0},
   {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
pbar = {.12, .10, .07, .03};
G = -1*IdentityMatrix[4];
h = MatrixForm[{1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00}];
b = MatrixForm[{1.00}];
numN = 100;
mus = Table[10.0^(5.0*i/100 - 1.0), {i, 100}];
```

Comment: A piece of advice. Never write an expression such as `h = MatrixForm[{1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00}];`  Be aware that `MatrixForm` is a tool for pretty-printing output. It returns an expression unusable in further computation. Write `MatrixForm[h = {1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00}]` if you want formatted output. Omit `MatrixForm` entirely if don't want to see any output  from the assignment.

Comment: @m_goldberg,Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did the same exercise myself the other day. Here is one way to do it.

edit: as noted by @DanielLichtblau, calling the method `"QuadraticProgramming"` in `FindMinimum` for this problem is much faster than the default (`"Automatic"`)

```
mS = {{0.04, 0.006, -0.004, 0.}, {0.006, 0.01, 0., 0.}, {-0.004, 0., 
    0.0025, 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.}};
vP = {0.12, 0.1, 0.07, 0.03};
vx = Array[x, 4];
muRange = 10.^(5 Range[0, 100, 1]/100 - 1);

s = Monitor[
      Table[
        {#[[1]], vx/.#[[2]]}&[
             FindMinimum[{-vP.vx + mu vx.mS.vx,Plus@@vx==1&&And@@Thread[vx>=0]}, vx, 
                          Method->"QuadraticProgramming"]
         ]
      ,{mu, muRange}
      ]
    ,mu
    ];
```

Plotting the results:

```
Grid[{{
   ListPlot[{Sqrt[#.mS.#], vP.#} & /@ s[[All, 2]], Joined -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.75, 
    Axes -> False, 
    FrameLabel -> {Text["standard deviation"], 
      Text["expected return"]}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.16}, 
    PlotLabel -> Text["Risk-return trade-off curve (Fig. 4.12a)"], 
    ImageSize -> 250],
   ListLinePlot[
    Transpose /@ ({Sqrt[#.mS.#] & /@ s[[All, 2]], #} & /@ 
       Transpose[Accumulate /@ s[[All, 2]]]), PlotStyle -> Blue, 
    PlotRangePadding -> None, 
    Epilog -> {Text["x(1)", {0.15, 0.5}], Text["x(2)", {0.10, 0.7}], 
      Text["x(1)", {0.05, 0.7}], Text["x(4)", {0.01, 0.7}]}, 
    FrameLabel -> {Text["standard deviation"], Text["allocation"]}, 
    PlotLabel -> Text["Optimal allocations (Fig. 4.12b)"], 
    ImageSize -> 250]
   }}]
```

[image][image]

Comment: Dear Stelios, Thank you.

Comment: @NelsonMok You are welcome.

Comment: Can get better speed with `Method -> "QuadraticProgramming"` (but this is quite nice regardless).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I wasn't aware of the existence of this method, It does provide significant performance gain! Thank you, I have edited the answer.

Comment: We really should implement `Method->"SpanishInquisition"` since nobody would ever expect it...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Stelios  Thank you.